# How to check which class invoked a method

Tags: java

I need to get the name of the class in an over-ridden method which has called the method

How can it be done?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want the name of the class which contains the code that called the method? The name of the class that first declared the method that is being overridden?

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please go in detail or community will close this question.

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName()？

Comment: @EJP I need the name of the class which calls the method using the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Throwable t = new Throwable(); 
StackTraceElement[] elements = t.getStackTrace();
```

[Class StackTraceElement has various methods like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)

```
String calleeMethod = elements[0].getMethodName(); 
String callerMethodName = elements[1].getMethodName(); 
String callerClassName = elements[1].getClassName();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the class of the current object inside your method using `this.getClass()`, or use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to walk the call path.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the class with:

```
class.getMethod("your_over-ridden_method_name").getDeclaringClass();
```

For example:

```
System.out.println(class.getMethod("your_over-ridden_method_name") + " declared by " + class.getMethod("your_over-ridden_method_name").getDeclaringClass());
```